# Why doesn't js allow methods as object key/value?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I was experimenting with some javascript when I came across a syntax error. I was trying to assign an object key with a value that is returned from a method.

```
var a = new function(){
    this.b = function()
    {
        return "c";
    }
};


var myobj = {
   a.b:"d" //Syntax error, unexpected '.'
};
```

The above will throw an error; but then javascript will allow:

```
var n = a.b;

var myobj = {
   n:"d" //no error
};
```

Even though `typeof a.b` and `typeof n` returns both the same as function?

Comment: `myobj.n` will return "d".  Starting with es6, you can put the variables in `[]` to use a variable as an object key. Though I don't think that that is what you want in this case.

Comment: The `n`  in `n:"d"` is the property with the name `n` and  is not related in any way to the `n` of `var n = a.b;`.

Comment: Why would you ever want a method to become a key? Or do you mean the name of a method as a key?

Comment: The return value of a.b is meant to become the name of the key

Comment: `var myObj = {}; myObj[a.b()] = "d";` I still can't think of a use case for this unless you're building like self modifying code. :)

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal), maybe dupe?  Same answer really, but question asked is a bit different.

Answer (score 2):

Though it seems very strange, but I expect you want to get a result if you log `myobj.c`. With es6 you can do the following:

```js
var a = function(){
    this.b = function()
    {
        return "c";
    }
};


var myobj = {
   [a.b()]:"d" 
};

console.log(myobj.c); // d
```

*But why would you ever want to do this?*

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're trying something like this?

```
var myobj = {
   "d": a.b
};
```

and then `myobj.d()` or @baao has already answered the other possibility?

Comment: myobj.d()???? d is a key-value pair NOT A FUNCTION

Comment: check my snippet, in that case its a function.

Comment: Yeah right. Forgot the type of a.b ... Sorry